# Add Button To Top Toolbar in Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor, buttons

I would like to add a button that triggers some custom JS code to the top roolbar (not the block level editor toolbar):

[image: Shows location of where the button should be added]

Is there an official way to do this? I couldn't find any documentation about extending the top toolbar.

Thanks
Aaron

Answer (score 1):

This is presently not offered as an extension point. [The source](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/164bef81386e96330128c6218a66f29c9ed8e865/packages/edit-post/src/components/header/header-toolbar/index.js) for the post editor's toolbar shows that these items are hard-coded, and do not offer any filters or Slotfills.

[Issue #16174](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/16174) provides a feature request for such extension points.

Comment: Thanks @bosco. I've actually went with inserting it using JS at the end.